# How to know the rows between random number sequence of total sum in laravel query builder?

Tags: laravel, sum, laravel-query-builder

```
Name    Sales
John    10
Jennifer15
Stella  20
Sophia  40
Greg    50
Jeff    20
```

I want to make a total sum list like below and radom a number to select the right row

```
SELECT a1.Name, a1.Sales, SUM(a2.Sales) Running_Total 
FROM Total_Sales a1, Total_Sales a2 
WHERE a1.Sales <= a2.Sales OR (a1.Sales=a2.Sales AND a1.Name = a2.Name) 
GROUP BY a1.Name, a1.Sales 
ORDER BY a1.Sales DESC, a1.Name DESC;
```

when I change it to the laravel query-builder

```
$total_grade=DB::query()
        ->select('a1.id','a1.Sales')
        ->addSelect(DB::raw('SUM(a2.Sales) as running total'))
        ->from('Total_Sales as a1')
              ->leftjoin('Toral_Sales as a2', function($join) {
                    $join->on('a1.id', '=', 'a2.id');
                    })
                ->groupBy('a1.id')
        ->where ('a1.Sales','<=','a2.Sales')
        ->orWhere('a2.id','=','a2.id')
        ->orderBy('a1.id')
        ->get();
```

I got the wrong 
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax

Cannot get the query result talbe.

```
id Name     Sales   Running_Total
1  Greg     50      50
2  Sophia   40      90
3  Stella   20      110
4  Jeff     20      130
5  Jennifer 15      145
6  John     10      155
```

So I  use the below to get the total num.

```
$total_sums=DB::table('adlists')
        ->select('countlast')
        ->get()
        ->sum('countlast');

$a=rand(1,$total_sums);


$sums=DB::table('adlists')
        ->select('countlast')
        ->get()
        ->each(function ($item, $key) 
            { 
                dump('$key='.$key);
                dump('$item->countlast='.$item->countlast);

                $total_item=$total_item+($item->countlast);

                if ( $a  < $total_item) 
                    { return $key.';'.$total_item; } ;
            });
```

I got the error

```
Undefined variable: total_items?
```

But how do I let the $a to find the right row ? ex $a=150 -> the right row is  id=3

Can laravel query builder make it happen one one code?

Comment: please explain how you have 150 on id 3

Comment: $a is a radom number. I just guess it is 150.  $a=rand(1,680)

Comment: and how you relate it to id `3`?

Comment: @Sohel0415  accumulation   id=1(1-50) id=2(51-140) id=3(141-250)